# Crawling another SharePoint farm slows down WFEs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

We have setup a new SharePoint 2013 farm and trying to crawl a different farm (MOSS 2007) in the same domain that has over 6 million items. We started the crawl and after 14 hours users started experiencing performance issue on the target farm. To complete our full crawl for that farm we need 6 days to complete the crawl, but since this affect performance on the target farm, we don't have the luxury to run full crawl for 6 days.

Any ideas or suggestion on how to complete our full crawl without affecting the performance on the target farm? Is there a way to make the crawler target a specific WFE on the remote farm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SharePoint 2007, add a hosts entry on your 2013 crawler to the specific WFE you want to crawl.